# Update a resource with associations in spring-data-rest

Tags: spring, associations, spring-data-rest

Let's say I have a `AFolder` class with name, description and a `List<AFile>` as an attribute. Now assume that I have created a `AFolder` object with its list of `AFile` populated. If I try to update using **PUT/PATCH** with something like `{"name": "new name", "description": "new description"}` then the list of `AFile` came back *empty*

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're running into [this issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-327) which has been fixed in Spring Data REST 2.1.1.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My code works after updating spring-data-rest to the latest version. :)

Answer (score 0):

The weird thing is that I got this situation too when I use Spring Data Rest 2.2.0.RELEASE,
and resolved this problem when changed the version to 2.1.1.